# DJANGO select FORM that is from a generated list and add an extra default value

Tags: django, list, select, django-forms

I want to have a select drop down form. In this example, i want to have a drop down of all division but it can include one more extra record (which is default=0).

How can I generate a list for select and append an additional item ?

models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)  
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division,null=True)

class Division(models.Model):
    name_of_division = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py

```
class EmployeeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)    
    division = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=XXXXWHATSHOULDIPUTHEREXXX)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("username","division")
```

for this variable, I want the list to be something like this but Im not sure how it should be coded:

```
XXXXWHATSHOULDIPUTHEREXXX = (0, Default) + Division.object.all()
```

For example it should generate something like this:

```
division
0 - default (this is not in the Division table) <-- i want to add this to the select list
1 - corporate
4 - human resource
7 - engineering
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead of just `ChoiceField`:

```py
class EmployeeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)    
    division = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, queryset=Division.object.all(), empty_label="(Default)")

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("username","division")
```

If you need to pass additional value to form - forms by itself doesn't have access to request object and therefore can't identify which user is currently logged. Your view should pass current user username instead:

```py
def index(request):
    # ...
    form = EmployeeEditForm(request.POST or None, company_id=request.user.employee.company.id)
    # ...
```

```py
class EmployeeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)    
    division = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, queryset=None, empty_label="(Default)")

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("username","division")    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        company_id = kwargs.pop('company_id')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['division'].queryset = Division.objects.filter(company_id=company_id)
```

Do not pass serialized object instances to form - use their `id` or `pk` instead and filter queryset in form by that `id`.

Comment: actually, it would work best with required=False. that did the trick. to an additional question if i would may, how do i pass parameter in the form to filter ? for example, queryset=Division.objects.filter(company=request.user.employee.company)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but within the for `__init__` you can specify the empty label.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['division'].empty_label = 'default'
```

Comment: i dont think is what i want, i made it a bit clear for XXXXWHATSHOULDIPUTHEREXXX. not sure what should be the code for this.

Comment: You can remove that line.  You don't need it.  It will then pick up all divisions and add the default.